# UIPickerView delegate not getting called

Tags: iphone

I have a UIPickerView in nib and three textfields. I am trying to display same pickerview for all three textfields. However, same data is displayed in the pickerview for all the three textfields. The delegate method is called only the first time. I think this is mainly because since the pickerView is in the nib it gets allocated only once when view loads. So how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reload pickerview data.

```
[self.picker reloadAllComponents];    //Reloading every component 
[self.picker reloadComponent:0];      // Reloading specific component
```